# 'Invalid object name' error for Common Table Expression (CTE) even though CTE has been defined

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I am using SQL server 2012. I have three CTEs defined in a row as shown below:

```
;WITH X_CTE (A, B, C, D)
AS (
    ...
)
,
Y_CTE (A, B, C, D)
AS (
    ...
)
,
Z_CTE (A, B, C, D)
AS (
    ...
)
```

Then, I insert these CTEs into a table, whose schema is defined and matches that of the CTEs

```
INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT * FROM X_CTE
INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT * FROM Y_CTE
INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT * FROM Z_CTE
```

I am getting a 'Invalid object name' error for the CTEs in the three `INSERT INTO` statements. In fact, I get the same errors with `SELECT` statements:

```
SELECT * FROM X_CTE
SELECT * FROM Y_CTE
SELECT * FROM Z_CTE
```

Would you please point out what is wrong here?

Thanks

-Rohan.

Answer (score 17):

CTEs are only defined for *one* statement that follows them. Three `INSERT` statements are - well - more than one statement.

Since all of the inserts are to the same table, you can do a `UNION ALL` to gather all of the rows into a single `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT * FROM X_CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Y_CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Z_CTE
```

But I'd also change the above to use explicit column lists - you don't want *this* query breaking if more columns are added to `MyTable` later:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (A,B,C,D)
SELECT * FROM X_CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Y_CTE
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Z_CTE
```

Answer (score 12):

The CTE's are defined only for one query.  You would need to repeat them for the three `select`s or `insert`s:

```
with X_CTE . . .
INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT * FROM X_CTE;

with X_CTE . . .
INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT * FROM Y_CTE;

with X_CTE . . .
INSERT INTO MyTable SELECT * FROM Z_CTE;
```

Comment: That is incorrect Gordon.  It is not an error to fail to use a CTE.

Comment: @N8allan . . . I removed the note.  I think that was true when CTEs were first introduced in SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are only selecting and running the select statement, you need to run all, the select and cte statements.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue on the first execution of a SQL function that contained a CTE. I was able to replicate the error every time after running:

```
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE(N'ALL');
```

The solution is simple, just recompile the function:

```
exec sp_refreshsqlmodule '<function-name>';
```